# A list of compiler rules for OCLint

Tags: objective-c, oclint, oclint-json-compilation

Is there a list of all **compiler** rules (not [OCLint rules](http://docs.oclint.org/en/stable/rules/index.html)) which `oclint` produceses with enabled option `-enable-clang-static-analyzer`?

What I'm looking for is for example `rule="clang static analyzer"` or `rule="compiler warning"` from the xml snippet below.

```
<violation begincolumn="1" endcolumn="0" beginline="27" endline="0" priority="2" rule="clang static analyzer" ruleset="clang" >
Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'xxx'
</violation>
</file>

<violation begincolumn="11" endcolumn="0" beginline="26" endline="0" priority="2" rule="compiler warning" ruleset="clang" >
unused variable 'xxx'
</violation>
</file>
```

Comment: I have found https://github.com/oclint/oclint/blob/master/oclint-reporters/reporters/PMDReporter.cpp and https://github.com/oclint/oclint/blob/master/oclint-reporters/test/PMDReporterTest.cpp from OCLint implementation. At least there are three rules defined: _"compiler error"_, _"compiler warning"_ and _"clang static analyzer"_.